# Injective chain map need not induce injective map on homology

Tags: examples-counterexamples, homology-cohomology, solution-verification

We recently introduced chain complexes in the algebraic topology course I'm taking; I'm currently trying to show that the map induced on homology by an injective chain map does not have to be injective itself. To do this, I constructed the following two bounded chain complexes, together with the chain map described by the vertical arrows:
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
0 @>{}>> \mathbb{Z} @>{\times 2}>> \mathbb{Z} @>{}>> 0\\
@. @V{\times 2}VV @V{id}VV @. \\
0 @>{}>> \mathbb{Z} @>{id}>> \mathbb{Z} @>{}>> 0
\end{CD}.
$$
The middle square commutes, so the vertical arrows really describe a chain homomorphism. It is also clear that each vertical arrow is injective. The homology of the first chain complex is $H_0^1 = \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ and $H_1^1 = 0$, and the homology of the second chain complex is $H_0^2 = H_1^2 = 0$. Clearly, the induced function $f_* : H_0^1 \to H_0^2$ can't be injective.

I still very new to chain complexes and homology, so a proof check would be appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Looks good. It's a good idea to avoid using upper indices (these are reserved for co-homology).

Comment: Nice! Okay, that's good to know. Thanks!

Comment: So, if $C_1$ and $C_2$ are two chain complexes, it reads better to write $H_n(C_j)$. Or, of course, the same if the $C_j$ are understood to be spaces instead.

Comment: Okay. I'm also trying to prove the same thing but regarding surjectivity. Using the "better notation", would the following commutative diagram suffice?

$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
C_1: \qquad 0 @>{}>> \mathbb{Z} @>{id}>> \mathbb{Z} @>{}>> 0\\
@. @V{id}VV @V{\pi}VV @. \\
C_2: \qquad 0 @>{}>> \mathbb{Z} @>{\pi}>> \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} @>{}>> 0,
\end{CD}
$$
where $\pi$ is the quotient homomorphism. This would give $H_1(C_1) = 0$ and $H_1(C_2) = 2\mathbb Z$, but there is no surjective function $0 \to 2\mathbb Z$.

Comment: Yup. That example works.

Comment: Cool! Thanks for the help. Finding these examples has been fun.